# Create a django background worker, best practices

Tags: django, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an API in Django, which should consume a RabbitMQ queue. I'm currently using [Amqpstorm Robust Consumer](https://www.amqpstorm.io/examples/robust_consumer.html), instantiated by [django command management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#command-objects), like this:

```
python3 manage.py mycommand.
```

and API runs in another container using `gunicorn`.

My queue has a high message rate coming in. My concern is if this is the best practice to run this kind of process in the background with django. Is there a better way to run this worker? I say this because my container is closing sporadically, without logging anyone, just this message:

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SXdz.png)

```
Killed.
```

Comment: Were you succeed with this?

Comment: Today we are running the async process with Celery Django. You can try that.